# Consider $T_s=\{∅\}\cup\{U\in P(\mathbb R)\mid ∀ x\in U,∃\epsilon\gt0:[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U\}$. Prove that $T_s$ is a topology over $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In $\mathbb R,$ consider the topology $T_s=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{U\in P(\mathbb R)\mid \forall x\in U,\exists\epsilon\gt0:[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U\}$. Prove that $T_s$ is a topology over $\mathbb R$.

Let's see if $T_s$ is closed under $\cup.$

Let $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\subset T_s.$

Let $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha $. We want to show that $x\in T_s$

As $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha, $ then $\exists\alpha_0\in I: x\in U_{\alpha_0}$.

But $x\in U_{\alpha_0}\subset \{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\subset T_s$. Thus $x\in T_s$

Now let's see if $T_s$ is closed under $\cap.$

Let $\{U_i:i\in I\}\subset T_s,$ where $I$ is finite.

Suppose $U_i\neq \emptyset,\forall i\in I$.

Let $x\in \bigcap U_i$, then $x\in U_i,\forall i$.

But $x\in U_i\subset \{U_i:i\in I\}\subset T_s$. Thus $x\in T_s$.

Please let me know if you find my proof correct.

Comment: No it's not correct. Note that you never used the _definition_ of the topology. Also, as an obvious indication that your proof is flawed, note that $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}$, so it's not an element of the topology. The elements of the topology are _subsets_ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Remember that the members of $T_s$ are sets, so it is not meaningful to say that $x \in T_s$, as $x$ is not a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to prove the wrong thing. The topology axioms are:

> Let $X$ be a set, a topology on $X$ is a collection $\tau$ **of subsets** of $X$ such that:
>
> 1. $X,\emptyset\in \tau$,
> 2. For every arbitrary collection $\{U_{\lambda }\in \tau : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ we have $\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda}U_\lambda \in \tau$
> 3. For every finite collection $U_1,\dots,U_k\in \tau$ we have $U_1\cap \cdots \cap U_k\in \tau$.

For this case (1) is trivialy verified. What you seem to be missing is that elements of the set $\tau$ are subsets of $X$. So a topology is a set of sets.

When you say that you must show that given $\{U_\alpha : \alpha \in I\}\subset T_s$ we must show that $x\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ implies $x\in T_s$ you are confusing things so it is important to point this out. For starters, you can't even have $x\in T_s$ because elements of $T_s$ are *subset of $\mathbb{R}$* and not numbers.

Now, how to do it correctly? Given $\{U_\alpha : \alpha \in I\}\subset \tau$ you need to show that $U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha\in \tau$. What it means to show that $U\in \tau$? It is either empty or satisfy the condition you mention. If it is empty there is nothing to prove. If it is not empty then you must show for all $x\in U$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ with $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U$.

That is what must be shown in the case of the union and similarly for the intersection. Now, if $x\in U$ there is $\lambda$ with $x\in U_\lambda$. If $x\in U_\lambda$ since $U_\lambda\in \tau$ it must be the case that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U_\lambda$. But $U_\lambda\subset U$, hence $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U$. Consequently for every $x\in U$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ with $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U$ and (2) is verified.

For three you do the same. Set $U=U_1\cap \cdots \cap U_k$. If $x\in U$ then $x\in U_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$. Since $U_i\in\tau$ there is $\epsilon_i>0$ with $[x,x+\epsilon_i)\subset U_i$.

Take $\epsilon = \min\{\epsilon_i\}$. Then since $\epsilon < \epsilon_i$ it follows that $x + \epsilon < x+\epsilon_i$ and thus since we are dealing with intervals $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset [x,x+\epsilon_i)$.

But $[x,x+\epsilon_i)\subset U_i$ for all $i$, hence $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U_i$ for all $i$ and by the very definition of the intersection we have $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset U$. Hence in accord to the definition of open sets you gave, (3) is verified.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's see if $T_s$ is closed under $\cup.$
>
> Let $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\subset T_s.$
>
> Let $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha $. We want to show that $x\in T_s$

That's not right; what you'd want to show is that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha \in T_s,$ not that a **member** of $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ is in $T_s.$

And the same applies to intersections.

Comment: It's a little bit strange to say $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha \in T_s$ since $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ is a set and $T_s$ is a set too. Wouldn't be more appropriate to use $\subset$ instead of $\in$ ?

Comment: @Isabella : No. Go back and read the definition of a topology. A topology is not a set of points in the underlying space; it's a set of sets of points in the underlying space.